# LINQ/Lambda - Getting parent object property while using Include to obtain children

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda, linq-to-entities

I am using this "model" from a previous question. Here I have a `Vehicle`,`VehicleType`, and `Price` entity.

```
public class Vehicle
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set}
    public int VehicleTypeId {get; set;}
    public virtual VehicleType VehicleType {get; set;}
}

public class VehicleType
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string VehicleTypeName {get; set}
    public ICollection<Vehicle> Vehicles {get; set;}
    public ICollection<Price> Prices {get; set;}
}

public class Price
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int Price {get; set;}
    public int VehicleTypeId {get; set;}
    public virtual VehicleType VehicleType {get; set;}
}
```

The `VehicleType` entity serves as a relationship to both the `Vehicle` entity and the `Price` entity. I am trying to use LINQ to get at the `Price` for a given `Vehicle` based upon it's `VehicleType`...

```
// Query #1 to get `Vehicle` name
var vehicle = dbContext.Vehicles.SingeOrDefault(v => v.Id = 1234);
string vehicleName = vehicle.Name;

// Query #2 to get lowest `Price` for `Vehicle`
var myVehiclePrice = dbContext.Vehicles.Include("VehicleType.Prices")
  .SingleOrDefault(v => v.Id == 1234)
  .VehicleType.Prices
  .OrderBy(p => p.PriceAmount).FirstOrDefault()
```

I have two queries to get the information I want. Is there a way to combine these two queries together to make one trip to the database? I tried reusing the `vehicle` variable obtained from the first query, but it represents a single entity and cannot make use of the `Include()` extension which only works off of an `object query`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are misinterpreting the `Include`. It's used for eagerly loading the **entity** content. It's not needed at all for queries that use selective projection of entity properties/aggregates.

You can gather the vehicle name and the lowest price with a single database trip simply with

```
var info = dbContext.Vehicles
    .Where(v => v.Id == 1234)
    .Select(v => new
    {
        VehicleName = v.Name,
        LowestPrice = v.VehicleType.Prices.Min(p => (int?)p.Price)
    })
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: The reason I used the include is that the foreign key or association in the entity was always coming up as null in the entity. If I added `Include` it was populated.

Comment: With this type of queries, you are not loading entities, i.e. no entity objects and or collections are really created. The navigation properties are used just as metadata for building the database SQL query.

Comment: So if all I am looking to do is get the Price and not a collection of entities then their is no need to us `Include()`?

Comment: Yes. Or better say, a collection or single item containing some information for entities, but projected in anonymous (or non entity) type, i.e. as in the example above, the result does not include your `Vehicle` entity class, but VehicleName, LowestPrice (and more if you wish). If you remove `Where` and `SingleOrDefault`, you'll get the same information for all vehicles.